# "Prevent" Programatic Click on Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Found this site the other day. You click on a DIV (button) and it increments getting you points.

http://clickingbad.nullism.com/

I thought to myself I'll just inject jQuery and write a loop to click for me use the Chrome developer console and run code similar to the following:

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{ 
    $('#make_btn').click();
}
```

However it doesn't seem to be working like I'd think. It will at like it increments the first hit, but past that nothing. Also you'll see when you acutally use your mouse to click, it floats the points given. Programatically clicking does not. What's going on here?

Comment: Site is using ajax to update the data on server. If it is not encrypted per click, you could just send the same ajax yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval() and use trigger('click')

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('#make_btn').trigger('click')
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

what using either the [**trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{ 
    $('#make_btn').trigger('click');
}
```

or use [**triggerHandler()**](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) method

> Execute all handlers attached to an element for an event.

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{ 
    $('#make_btn').triggerHandler('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply the original function manipulate some event property that a simple `trigger('click')` do not pass.

Try this

```
var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.pageX = e.pageY = 140;
for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
{ 
    setTimeout(function() {$('#make_btn').trigger(e)},100*i);
}
```

`setTimeout` for a nice effect and in order to prevent this check by site developer(from page source)

```
this.do_make_click = function() { 
        var nw = (new Date).getTime();
        if((nw - last_click) < 70) { 
            return false;
        }
        //...
}
```